# Как в cmd получить все процессы которые активны в сети?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, windows-7

Подскажите cmd команду для получения активных в сети процессов и желательно получить информацию о том сколько byte передано и принято

Comment: воспользуйтесь утилитой **netstat /?**

Comment: Этой утилитой я могу получить общие данные по сетевым протоколам, но без разбивки по процессам, или возможностью получить данные по PID, так же при использовании поиска по PID нет возможности посмотреть общую статистику (хотя опять же она мне не нужна), не подходит или покажите cmd запрос

Comment: Для того, чтобы получить разбивку по процессам, надо сперва создать счетчики, запустить подсчет, а затем получить результаты расчетов. netstat показывает **общую** статистику (хотя есть отдельно Ethernet, IPv4 и IPv6). Есть счетчик **Сетевой интерфейс** **Монитора производительности**. Однако для калькуляции объема трафика процессов, скорее всего, понадобятся утилиты типа TCPView.

Comment: Я получаю с помощью WMI сетевые интерфейсы + все процессы, поэтому могу передать PID и сетевой интерфейс, только вот получается что я никак не получу информацию... а могу я получить инфу как в диспетчере задач столбец "Сеть" хотя бы процент использования сети... было бы тоже не плохо

Comment: Видимо, я предыдущим комментарием Вас дезинформировал. Я имел в виду, что для подсчета нужно начать считать. Из имеющихся **встроенных** (**системных**) счетчиков Windows есть: "I/O обмен данными байт/с" - для **Процессов** и счетчики - для **Сетевого интерфейса**. Счетчик I/O считает обмен всех данных процесса - сетевой интерфейс, дисковые операции и память. А сетевой интерфейс - для всех процессов. Поэтому для точного подсчета нужны внешние решения: драйвер WinpCap , агенты мониторинга инфраструктуры типа Pandora FMS, готовые утилиты TCPView и т.д.

Comment: Жаль что нельзя вычислить по каждому процессу отдельно (((

Comment: Забыл упомянуть ещё такое средство, как встроенный **Аудит Windows**. При активации соответствующих функций (можно через Редактор локальной групповой политики), в журнале событий появляются записи о том, какой процесс открывал порты для межсетевого взаимодействия.